# EC2 instance with two ENIs and public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

When launching an EC2 instance with multiple network interfaces AWS doesn't allow the public IP assignment option.

However, one can perform a cold or hot attach of an ENI to an instance which has already one network interface and a public IP. This technically allows to have an EC2 instance with multiple ENI and a public IP (though this public IP will be released after this instance restarting).

Essentially I don't understand this logic and would like to know from which technical reasons this limitation comes from.

**UPD:** Just to give you an idea how strange this limitation is: basically it means that if one wants to have such an instance, he/she can do that by writing a lambda function which will assign a second ENI to the instance once it has started with a single ENI and a public IP (and another lambda will do an opposite operation - detach the ENI from the rebooted/stopped instance). This is a fairly cheap workaround, which costs almost nothing.